# Angular passing object to child component

Tags: angular

I have an ngFor directive like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas|slice:0:2"><app-data [data]="data"></app-data></div>
```

But the data object is not getting passed into the app-data component from the enclosing div.

How do I pass data from the div to app-data?

Comment: This should work, have you tried to console log the data object?

Comment: I'm getting a NaN. Not even undefined.

Comment: Please share the code where you define `data`

Comment: @Latcie please check my below answer and if u clear with my answer that vote up and mark as good answers it will help to other.

Answer (score 2):

## Parent Component

---

You can use Simply

For Example I have **parent Component** like this

```
<div *ngFor="let data of datas|slice:0:2">
    <app-child [data]="data"></app-child>
</div>
```

**TS**

I have Dummy array

```
 datas = [
    {id: 1, name: 'ABC'},
    {id: 2, name: 'EFG'}
  ];
```

## Child Component

---

now you can use this array to **child component** like this

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{data.id}}</li>
    <li>{{data.name}}</li>     
</ul>
```

**TS**

```
// This will bring data from parent component and this is used for sharing data between parent context and child directives or components
@Input() data;

ngOnInit() {
  console.log('data => ', this.data);
}
```

My Example you can check it [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwamxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)